# Postfix virtual: parent domain matches subdomains - I don't want it

Tags: virtual, postfix-mta

I have my /etc/postfix/virtual file:

```
sub.domain.com DOMAIN
@sub.domain.com user2

domain.com DOMAIN
@domain.com user1
```

The mail for @sub.domain.com still goes to user1 and that's not what I want.
Here's my /etc/postfix/my.cnf just in cases:

```
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = mail.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
parent_domain_matches_subdomains =
```

Note, that I set parent_domain_matches_subdomains to empty. But it still doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side of your virtual_alias_maps table is an unqualified username.

Postfix appends $myorigin to unqualified usernames, making it effectively

@sub.example.com  user2@example.com
@example.com      user1@example.com

Now user2@example.com is caught by the catchall for @example.com.

Hence, mail for user2@example.com goes to user1.

You could change your Postfix config to this:

```
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
parent_domain_matches_subdomains =
virtual_alias_domains = sub.example.com
luser_relay = user2@example.com
```

/etc/postfix/virtual
@sub.example.com   user1@example.com

Create two system accounts user1 and user2.

Comment: Slightly simpler solution, but your answer helped me to find it: I just appended @localhost to user1 and user2 in my /etc/postfix/virtual file.